# Generating Solution/Project diagram in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a VS 2012 solution which has many class projects inside it. Now i need to generate a diagram which can depict me overall view of the solution and help me visualize how all the projects are structured and how they are interrelated.

I dont see "Architecture" menu option also.

How to resolve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UML Modeling support available only in VS2012 Ultimate and Premium family of products. VS2012 Professional did not support UML modeling.

Samething holds good for VS2010 version.

check the link for further information

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare

Comment: And to view and get an diagramatic overview of different layers of the big enterprise project, we have to use Layer diagram. 
check the link for a video tutorial for the layer diagram:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/clinted/UML-with-VS-2010-Part-5-Architecting-an-Application